# Script to restart a process exceeding RAM

Tags: perl, shell, powershell, vbscript, autohotkey

I want to write a script which can run as a Windows service. It would restart a process active in the process table when the user is using the process and it exceeds for example 500mb of RAM. How can I do this? Can someone suggest any example?

Answer (score 3):

There's always the dirty way. Using `tasklist` in Windows:

```
use List::Util qw<first>;

my ( $mem )      
    = map   { ( my $a = $_ ) =~ s/,//g; $a } 
      grep  {; length } 
      map   { m/([\d,]+)[ ]K$/ } 
      first { m/^perl\.exe\s+$$\b/ } 
      `tasklist`;

if ( $mem > MAX_MEM ) {
    do_something();
}
```

But as I understand it, you could also do it like this, with [`Win32::Process::Info`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess%3a%3aInfo):

```
use Win32::Process::Info;
my  $pi = Win32::Process::Info->new ();
my $set = first { exists $_->{WorkingSetSize} } $pi->GetProcInfo( $$ );
my $mem = $set && $set->{WorkingSetSize};
```